# Why does my UIButton delegate have to execute entirely before changes are shown in view?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm doing some MonoTouch development, and I really can't figure out an problem I've run into

I'm having an ViewController containing a UIButton. I have added a delegate to the TouchDown event of this button. In this delegate I'm calling a WebService and trying to change the colour and title of the button. However nothing happens to the button before the entire delegate have been executed. The thing is that the webservice is rather slow, so I want to give the users a waiting message by changing the colour and title of the button.

The code:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

        bookButton = new UIButton( new RectangleF(10,100,this.View.Frame.Width-10 ,40) );

        bookButton.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        setButton();

        bookButton.TouchDown += delegate {

            gymClass.book();
            setButton();
            tableView.ReloadData();
            NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated( true );

        };

        this.View.AddSubview( bookButton );

    }
```

Anyone, please?

Comment: Are you calling a web service on tableView.ReloadData()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate is executed on the main thread which is responsible for rendering, so you are blocking the renderer until you return.

Comment: Aha. OK, I resolved this by using the TouchUpInside event instead. Thanx